# (Discord Bot) Get message that follows command prefix

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm trying to reference the previous message sent by a client using discord.js

How would I go about getting the last message sent?

````
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {

    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'set-reminder'){
        channelName = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "spam");

        message.channel.send("Command Works"); 
        channelName.messages.fetch({ limit: 1 }).then(messages => {
    // find "command works" message (previous message from client)
           let lastMessage = messages.first();
          
           console.log(lastMessage.content);
        })
    }
})```
````

Answer (score 1):

The [message.channel.send function](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.TextChannel.send) is async

You can **await** the send function or use **.then**

The send function also returns the [message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message), you don't need a query to get it

await

```
let message = await message.channel.send("Command Works");
console.log(message.content);
```

then

```
message.channel.send("Command Works").then((message) => {
   console.log(message.content);
});
```

(async means not-synchronous : you have to wait to get its result)

Comment: Thank you. Where would I use the await / then? I know you said these are asynchronous. Should I make a separate function to listen for the response?

Comment: @Matt you would just replace the line `message.channel.send("Command Works");` with one of the options, after that, you can continue your code. In both examples the result is printed, no need to make another function

Comment: Also, how would I go about waiting for a response (then viewing and doing stuff) from the same user who used the prefix?

Comment: @Matt to wait for another message of the same user you could make a dictionary outside the function with a function to be called.
e.g. outside: `var waitingList = [];`
After message.channel.send: `waitingList[message.author.id] = function(msg){console.log(msg)}` 
At the start of your function:

`const call = waitingList[message.author.id];
if (call) {
   delete waitingList[message.author.id];
   call(message);
}`